# Composite key insertion in codeginiter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3, composite-key

I have a composite key created on(courseID,lessonID,studID) on a table.

I am trying to insert duplicate value on composite key columns obviously, we will get duplicate entry error.

What I am trying to achieve is to avoid checking it before inserting, if there is a value on composite key or not.

is there a way to avoid the double-checking step!

CodeIgniter is missing something like insert ignore.

is there a way to omit duplicate insert error from CodeIgniter side since it is composite key!